# How to enable Stylus url() rewrites

Tags: javascript, css, gruntjs, stylus

I'm trying to get stylus urls to work.  I would like to convert the `url('/path/to/img.png')` to convert to the base64 encoded form.

I'm trying to follow the documentation [here](http://learnboost.github.io/stylus/docs/functions.url.html), but it's not helping me much.

I tried adding the require bit and the example functions, importing `url`, but not sure how to enable this thing.

How do I get this to work?

**UPDATE:**

Trying to use [grunt-image-embed](https://npmjs.org/package/grunt-image-embed) plugin.

Here is my grunt config:

```
imageEmbed: {
  dist: {
    src: [ "./public/local/css/images.css" ],
    dest: "./public/prod/css/images.css",
    options: {
      deleteAfterEncoding : false
    }
  }
},
```

And the css contains:

```
#footer-social .youtube {
  width: 18px;
  background-image: url('/img/youtube-icon.png');
}
```

Which produces the error:

```
Warning: File C:\path\...\grunt-image-embed\tasks\lib\img\youtube-icon.png
does not exist Use --force to continue.
```

If I remove the `background-image` line it all works and goes through fine.  I can't modify the paths in the css because on `local` we use the relative path to the actual image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you'll find this grunt plugin to be exactly what you need; [grunt image embed](https://github.com/ehynds/grunt-image-embed). Works for both images and fonts. From the docs:

```
grunt.initConfig({
  imageEmbed: {
    dist: {
      src: [ "css/styles.css" ],
      dest: "css/output.css",
      options: {
        deleteAfterEncoding : false
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Why is it trying to load the images from node folder? `Running "imageEmbed:dist" (imageEmbed) task
Warning: File C:\...\node_modules\grunt-image-embed\tasks\lib\img\audio.png does not exist Use --force to continue.`

Comment: My paths are like so: `.audio{background-image:url('/img/audio.png')}`

Comment: Could you paste your config into pastebin or similar so I could have a look at it?

Comment: Sorry for late reply, I updated the original question with sample config.

Comment: Right, OK. I can replicate the issue in the question. Basically the leading slash is throwing the whole thing off, just remove that (or prepend a . so your path reads `./img/audio.png`) and you'll be good to go. :-)

Comment: Okay ya, setting it to "../../img/audio.png" did the trick.  Should have thought of that.  Thanks for your patience in helping me with this.

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
function compile(str, path) {
  return stylus(str)
            .define('url', stylus.url({
              paths : [__dirname + '/public'],
              limit : 10000
            }));
}
```

From here:

```
http://bengourley.co.uk/using-stylus
```

It worked for me here:

```
https://github.com/MichaelJCole/wintersmith-stylus/blob/master/plugin.coffee
```

It's coffeescript, and the interesting part is this:

```
      stylus(@_text, options)
      .use(nib())
      .define('url', stylus.url(
        paths : [__dirname + '/public']
        limit : locals.inlineSpriteMaxBytes || 0 ) )
      .render (err, css) ->
        if err
          callback err
        else
          callback null, new Buffer css
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not know how it makes no a stylus, but you can use this [1]: http://docs.emmet.io/actions/base64/